# Unable to access JSONArray

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I am developing a phonegap plugin for android. Here I am returning a `JSONArray` from `callBackContext.sendPluginResult(result);`. Below is how I developed the `JSONArray`

```
private JSONArray makeJsonObject(String type, String result, float confidence)
{
    JSONObject recogResult = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try
    {
        recogResult.put("type", type);
        recogResult.put("result", result);
        recogResult.put("confidence", confidence);

        jsonArray.put(recogResult);
        //jsonObject.put("recognitionResults", recogResult);

    }
    catch(JSONException  e)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "JSON Error", e);
    }

    return jsonArray;
}
```

Above method generates a result like below.

`[{"type":"interim","result":"da","confidence":0}]`

Below is how I read it via javascript.

```
 function startRecognition()
 {
      SpeechRecPlug.startRecognition(function(msg){
          var data = msg;
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      var div = document.getElementById("test");
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + " "+ json[1].result;

    });
 }
```

But the issue is, in the HTML, nothing is getting printed. Not sure whether there is an issue in the way I am trying to print using Javascript.

Any idea please?

**UPDATE**
I noticed that I am getting the below message from android console

```
01-19 12:54:57.946: I/chromium(30192): [INFO:CONSOLE(310)] "Error in Success callbackId: SpeechRecPlug1992021962 : SyntaxError: Unexpected token o", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (310)
```

Comment: is there any element by name "test" ?

Comment: @PankajNimgade: Yes there is. It is the id of the DIV

Comment: it is supposed to be id of div

Comment: @Sachin: Yes. It is the ID

Comment: @Tracer: Have you tired `json[0].result` ?

Comment: the `json` array what you are getting at the client side is an `array of objects`,but  looks like in your case it is containing just a single object, so use index zero like @ρяσѕρєяK has mentioned

Comment: @dreamweiver: I did. No results.

Comment: why dont you console log the content of  `json`, `console.log(JSON.stringify(json));`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: If there any error with the android side, when it comes to the `float` value? I am getting the below message from android console. `01-19 12:54:57.946: I/chromium(30192): [INFO:CONSOLE(310)] "Error in Success callbackId: SpeechRecPlug1992021962 : SyntaxError: Unexpected token o", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (310)
`

Comment: @Tracer: what is line number `310 ` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: It is refering to a line number in cordova (cordova.js). Built in thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the property in jsonArray before printing inside div element.

```
if(jsonArray.hasOwnProperty('type') ){ 
         document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = json[0].result;        
     }
```

Comment: this should be a suggestion bro, since your not providing a solution rather best ways to handle data.